# floating button activity not open when i click on first item

Tags: java, android

i'm newbie... i added floating button in my app and added one click activity in first item but when i click on first item application get unfortunately stop help me...

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FloatingActionMenu materialDesignFAM;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton1, floatingActionButton2, floatingActionButton3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        materialDesignFAM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.material_design_android_floating_action_menu);
        floatingActionButton1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.material_design_floating_action_menu_item1);
        floatingActionButton2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.material_design_floating_action_menu_item2);
        floatingActionButton3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.material_design_floating_action_menu_item3);
        floatingActionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // first item
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        floatingActionButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        floatingActionButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    }
```

[image: see in screenshot]

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: can you add the exception & xml file??

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add your activity to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: how plz tell me i'm very new

Comment: Check out this one: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Well then. Is your onClick() method even called?

Comment: can you provide me your layout i will check and revert you and are you using any  library for this